# What are the four vertical structures surrounding Falcon launch?

Tags: falcon-9, launchpad

[image]

This image is on the first page of the [Falcon 9 Launch Vehicle PAYLOAD  USER’S  GUIDE](https://www.spacex.com/sites/spacex/files/falcon_9_users_guide_rev_2.0.pdf) which features Falcon blasting off and four masts with cables attached to their tops.

What are they?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lightning towers. Designed to get attract lightning strikes, instead of the booster.