# Was there a thunderstorm in Florida during the Crew Dragon Demo 1 launch?

Tags: spacex, dragon-v2

The [video from SpaceX this morning](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2ZL0tbOZYhE) shows a number of red flashes in the sky at T-00:20:34, T-00:09:36, T-00:04:50 and T-00:02:15.  The most noticeable was at T-00:04:50.  These flashes look like lightning from a distant thunderstorm.  The presenters said the weather was perfect for launch

There was also a flash seen from the descending first stage at T+00:03:24, but that may be unrelated

I've checked the METARs for Cocoa Beach at the time, at www.ogimet.com, but can't see any mention of CBs

Does anyone know if there really was a storm in the area, at that time?

Comment: There's a 'special'  METAR for Daytona Beach a few hours earlier that mentions thunderstorms, cumulonimbus and towering cumulus  -  SPECI KDAB 012206Z 19005KT 10SM TS FEW045CB FEW080 BKN160 BKN250 26/17 A3007 RMK AO2 LTG DSNT NW-NE TSE00B06 OCNL LTGICCG N-NE TS N-NE MOV E TCU DSNT SW T02610172=

Comment: comments on the following pages may contain helpful background information and links on regulations and practices related to nearby/distant lightning events: [1](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/32927/12102), [2](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/2958/12102), [3](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/32618/12102) Also here's a random screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1DWD.jpg

Comment: @uhoh +1 -  Do SpaceX have also have a steely-eyed missile man on the staff?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Aaron         :)